# height of cards base on widgets height flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, height, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I want to set the height for my cards based on the height of the widgets in it.
I use `globalKey` and set it in my widget but return null.

can anyone help me how can I do that?

```
 final GlobalKey _Key = GlobalKey();


 showModalBottomSheet(
                        context: context,
                        useRootNavigator: true,
                        isScrollControlled: true,
                        isDismissible: true,
                        enableDrag: true,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return Container(
                            key : _key,
                            child: ListView(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              children: [
                                PressWidget(),
                                PaddingButtonCard(),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
```

when I print `_Key.currentContext?.findRenderObject().size`  , return null.

Comment: You would need to do this call after the widget has been built, not inside the build function. Do you already do this? (If not, you can try it out by simply making a button in your interface print this value). I'm not entirely sure how the `size` works, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

A Widget like a card should automatically wrap it's contents, so unless the contents have an unconstrained height (like a `ListView` or `Expanded` widget), you shouldn't need measuring or such techniques to achieve this.

Try, as a test, putting a `Container` with a set `height` inside your `Card`, and observe how the card automatically sizes itself:

```dart
Card(
  child: Container(
    height: 40,
    width: double.maxFinite,
    color: Colors.purple,
    child: Text('Purple Card'),
  ),
),
```